# How to implement attribute driven visibility of Kendo grid columns?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Following is the Kendo Grid in one of my MVC view -

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel>()
.Name("EmployeeGrid")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("AdminEmployeeSearchData", "Employee").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
        .ServerOperation(true)
        )
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeID).Title("ID")
    columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeName).Title("Employee Name")
    columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeSalary).Title("Employee Salary")
})
.AutoBind(false)
.Sortable()
.EnableCustomBinding(true)
```

)

Here, EmployeeSalary column is supposed to be visible to specific roles. 
In order to achieve that, one simple approach is to use IF...ELSE block in the view where I will validate the current user role, and based on it will display/ hide the column. But this is bound to become unmanageable once we have a number of columns in the grid.

I am thinking to drive this through Attribute at the field level of the view model. That is, EmployeeSalary field will have some attribute say "IsAccessible" and the logic would be at the attribute level. And based on the result the Kendo grid should display/ hide that column.

Could anyone please suggest how we can achieve this?

Also, let me know if anything is unclear here.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just something like `columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeSalary).Title("Employee Salary").Visible(Model.IsManager)` unless it changes by row in which case you will need to handle the DataBound event.

Comment: @SteveGreene this is the answer I would suggest too and most probably the right answer for this question through the options that kendo grid gives you. I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Hi @SteveGreene, yes, please post this as an answer, so we can mark it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a model property that determines visibility you, can use the MVC wrapper's [Visible property](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridColumnBuilderBase#methods-Visible(System.Boolean)). So for example:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeSalary).Title("Employee Salary").Visible(Model.IsManager)
```

Comment: For completion you could add the Hidden property too which pretty much does the exact opposite to Visible.(https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridColumnBuilderBase#methods-Hidden)